# Unclear about SLIB packages - am I meant to define my own, or is it only for SLIB's internal use?

Tags: package, scheme

Basically, what the title says. Is SLIB's package system meant to be 'a package system for Scheme', or is it just 'a way of loading only the features of SLIB you personally need at this time'?

Comment: Which Scheme system do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The background for SLIB's package system is that no package/module system were standardized in r5rs, r4rs and earlier. SLIB therefore comes with its own package system. Normally my advice would be to use the module system of the Scheme implementation you have chosen - and only use the SLIB ones to load what you need.
However it seems there is no builtin module system in MIT (GNU) Scheme - so try the package system in SLIB and see if you like it.

Consider asking that the MIT Scheme mailing list what the plans for a module system is. Maybe there is one underway?